# Including a jpg image, source code compilation in pdflatex doesn't create pdf

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I'm writing a report on a programming project in LaTeX and need to insert some images. I created images using a Finite Element program Freefem++, and saved the results in image files. I've tried png, jpeg, eps, and ps, but would like to use jpg, and none of them work so far. I've searched all over the internet, and it seems like my code should work, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{images/}}
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.jpg}   

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}


The domain considered will be

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{domain.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I've tried with the file in a folder images and in the same folder as the doc, I've tried with and without the file extension, with and without `[pdftex]` and `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions`, etc. 
It compiles with `pdflatex` and gives no errors, exit code 1, then when I try to view the pdf it says it doesn't exist, and asks if I've compiled the source code. If I compile with `pdftex`, it just creates a blank first page.
I've tried everything I can think of, I don't know what I'm missing. Perhaps a package I need to install on my computer? Or just a stupid mistake in the code?
Does anyone see my error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What happens if you try to open the pdf using another application (e.g. Adobe Reader)? Also, what happens if you compile using pdflatex from the command line?

Comment: It doesn't even create a pdf file to open when I compile it. I haven't tried compiling from the command line, I'll give that a try.

Comment: I get this error in terminal: !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./domain.jpg): reading JPEG image failed (no JPEG
 header found)
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: Can you make the jpg file available for download?

Comment: I cannot, I don't think I have enough reputation first of all, but I tried anyway, and it said the image format wasn't supported... which is weird because it's a .jpg... so perhaps it's because of the way my program exports the image? In which case I guess I'm glad my professor is the one who wrote the program, he might know what to do!

Comment: I think there is probably something wrong with the image. If you can make the file available for download from somewhere else on the web, you can add a link here.

Comment: As the other comments say, your image isn't being understood for some reason. Try leaving out the extension, check (using an image viewer) that the image *is* there, on Linux/MacOS the `file(1)` command should tell you what the image file really contains (perhaps some tool-specific format, or some different format than you think?).

Comment: What's interesting is that the same images, sent via email, work on my partner's computer, and the same code from her has the same problem on my computer... I'm very confused. I downloaded all the extra tex packages in case I was missing something (I needed a package to use changepage anyway), and my computer spent a couple hours downloading and installing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem: apparently `Freefem++` creates `.jpg`, `.png`, etc. images that are not readable by LaTeX. Thanks to the comments above telling me it was a problem with the image, I decided to try converting it to `.jpeg` (other formats probably would have worked as well, but I wanted `jpg`). To do this, I installed the ImageMagick package from terminal in linux, then used the `convert` command to create `domain.jpeg`:

```
$ convert domain.JPG domain.jpeg
```

This made the image usable, after that it was just formatting to get it to look right.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the same error with pandoc when trying to convert epub
to pdf :

```
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$ pandoc -s -t latex --toc --chapters \
    --latex-engine=lualatex $BOOK.epub -o $BOOK.pdf
!LuaTeX error (file /tmp/tex2pdf.23440/3f21bef8dd2877aad72f5cddbf00284ca88fa0e7
.jpg): reading JPEG image failed (no marker found)
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

pandoc: Error producing PDF
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$
```

Here's a workaround. Check to see if a tex file can be produced :

```
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$ pandoc \
    -s -t latex \
    --toc --chapters \
    --latex-engine=lualatex $BOOK.epub -o $BOOK.tex
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$
```

Extract images and other media contained in the epub container to the 
path DIR, creating it if necessary, and adjust the images references in 
the [LaTeX] document so they point to the extracted files, with the 
option --extract-media= DIR . Select the current directory which also 
contains the ePub file. Add  --extract-media=. which means extract in 
the current directory, which is also $HOME/Documents

```
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~)$ cd Documents
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$ pandoc \
    -s -t latex \
    --toc --chapters \
    --latex-engine=lualatex \
    --extract-media=. $BOOK.epub -o $BOOK.tex
pandoc: extracting ./images/9781501144158.jpg
pandoc: extracting ./images/com-01.jpg
pandoc: extracting ./images/f0003-01.jpg
pandoc: extracting ./images/f0005-01.jpg
[ ----- extract-media logging shortened ---- ]
pandoc: extracting ./images/f0177-01.jpg
pandoc: extracting ./images/f0187-01.jpg
pandoc: extracting ./images/logo.jpg
pandoc: extracting ./images/logo1.jpg
pandoc: extracting ./images/title.jpg
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$
```

Repeal the extracted .jpg images by creating new LaTeX compatible JPEG 
images with the `convert' utility (from the imagemagick program suite)

```
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$ cd images
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents/images)$ convert logo1.jpg logo1.jpeg
```

and Replace the previously with pandoc extracted .jpg images with the 
newly created .jpeg images :

```
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents/images)$ mv logo1.jpeg logo1.jpg
```

One can do this with a single for loop on the commandline :

```
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$ 
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$ cd images/
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents/images)$ for i in *.jpg; do convert $i `echo $i | sed 's/jpg/jpeg/'`; done
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents/images)$ rm -f *.jpg
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents/images)$ for i in *.jpeg; do mv $i `echo $i | sed 's/jpeg/jpg/'`; done 
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents/images)$ cd ..
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$
```

Run the first commandline again, but this time have the LuaTeX engine
seek for its \includegraphics in the same directory as where the ePub
images were extracted earlier 
( --data-dir=DIRECTORY
   Specify the user data directory to search for pandoc data files.
   If this option is not specified, the default user data directory
   will be used.  This is, in Unix: $HOME/.pandoc )
by adding the option --data-dir=. :

```
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$ pandoc \
    -s -t latex \
    --toc --chapters \
    --latex-engine=lualatex \
    --data-dir=. $BOOK.epub -o $BOOK.pdf
[macfarlane@boulder]:(~/Documents)$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please shorten this to the necessary details and then explain what you did.